# How do I make a pull request from the master to the staging branch?

Tags: git, github

I have many changes in the master. I want to do a pull request to the staging branch so that it can later merge to staging. I tried as the picture below, but nothing changes

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Change the "base" selection to `staging` and the "compare" to `master`. The configuration currently shown in the screenshot is setting up for merging `staging` into `master` (and obviously there are no changes). Consider rebasing `staging` on top of `master` instead of doing a pull request unless you need the pull request to discuss something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the base from `master` to `staging`.  The base branch is the branch that you are going to merge into.

Furthermore, [Github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) explains:

> After initializing a pull request, you'll see a review page that shows a high-level overview of the changes between your branch (the compare branch) and the repository's base branch.

Answer (score 4):

**Rebase**

If you are trying to ensure staging is back at the same state as 'master' you can "re-base" it:

From the 'staging' branch

`git rebase master`

---

**Alternatively**:

Have you made sure to push your local commits to github (remote) ?

First ensure you're on the new branch:

`git checkout staging`

** Make some changes to local files example.js

Stage any changes made in the project directory:

`git add .`

Commit the changes locally:

`git commit -m "My commit message"`

Push the commit to the remote (github):

`git push origin staging`

If you try to make a pull request into 'master' on github you should now see the new commit.